# Removing flickering when hiding/showing toolbar

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-toolbar

my app uses a toolbar that hides or shows when the user scrolls the listview. However there seems to be a werd issue, when scrolling the toolbar flickers. I tried to dig more information and unfortunately I was not able to fix this issue. The listview is located inside a fragment. If you have any ideas or would like me to provide more information please let me know. Thank you!

MainActivity:

```
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);//does not solve flickering
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
// code to create fragments
```

Fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//populate list code

newslist.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
            int mLastFirstVisibleItem = 0;

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

            }

            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount){
                if (view.getId() == newslist.getId()) {

                        final int currentFirstVisibleItem = newslist.getFirstVisiblePosition();

                        if (currentFirstVisibleItem > mLastFirstVisibleItem) {

                            if (((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().isShowing()) {
                                ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
                            }

                        } else if (currentFirstVisibleItem < mLastFirstVisibleItem) {

                            if (!((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().isShowing()) {
                                ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
                            }

                        }


                        mLastFirstVisibleItem = currentFirstVisibleItem;

                }


            }


        });
```

xml:

```
       <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listitems"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"/>
```

xml called in Main activity:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>
```

Comment: Maybe what you want is `CoordinatorLayout`  https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout

Comment: Hello @nshmura thank you for your response, this looks great however it seems it uses recycle view instead of a listview?